# SSL Certificates in PCI DSS compliance

Tags: tls, pci-dss

I have come across the PCI DSS compliance which expects SSL certificates to comply with certain standards. I have come across this link which highlights :

1. The latest PCI DSS 3.2 requires migration from early SSL/TLS version 1.0 to a secure version v1.1 or higher.
2. Strong Private Key For RSA: 2048-bit+, For EC: 256-bit+
3. Check the validity of the certificate (expiry)

Is there anything else to do to satisfy the PCI compliance regarding SSL or am I missing out anything?

Comment: Could you include the link you found please

Comment: The PCI documentation will tell you what it expects.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot to the PCI Standards that you'll have to get by reading [the most recent standards](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-2.pdf?agreement=true&time=1515093222082). Read these standards in conjunction with the [glossary](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_Glossary_v3-2.pdf), where it will explain things like what they consider "strong cryptography." For instance, PCI defines strong cryptography as:

> AES (128 bits and higher), TDES/TDEA (triple-length keys), RSA (2048 bits and higher), ECC (224 bits and higher), and DSA/D-H (2048/224 bits and higher).

To clarify something from #1 in your question, PCI is requiring migration from SSL (any version) and early TLS (version 1.0). The terminology PCI uses is "SSL/early TLS." More about the migration can be found in PCI's information supplement, [Migrating from SSL and Early TLS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/Migrating-from-SSL-Early-TLS-Info-Supp-v1_1.pdf?agreement=true&time=1498138739969), or in Appendix A2 of the current standards linked above.